# Disable custom icons within applications

Tags: icons

I like the default icons in Elementary, however when I change the icon theme to Numix it also replaces the icons in applications (for instance Midori) which looks really out of place.

Any way to change that?

Edit: What I precisely meant is that icons within applications (such as back, forward, refresh, &c) are replaced with custom ones. I want to keep those the elementary default.

Answer (score 1):

Gtk applications, like Midori, use gtk stock icons from selected theme to show actions WITHIN headerbars.

You can make a variant of the Numix theme to solve your issue.

First of all,  create a new folder from terminal:

```
mkdir -p ~/.icons/mynumix
```

Copy the content of Numix theme icon folder to new one:

```
sudo cp -a /usr/share/icons/Numix/. ~/.icons/mynumix
```

Copy the gtk stock icons to "mynumix" folder:

```
sudo cp -a /usr/share/icons/elementary/actions/24/* ~/.icons/mynumix/24/actions/
```

Create icon cache for the new theme:

```
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache ~/.icons/mynumix
```

And finally, change to new theme:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'mynumix'
```

To restore to default theme, just execute from terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'elementary'
```

You can combine sizes and themes changing the words '24' and 'elementary' by your favorite ones when you copy the stock icons.

Comment: I would suggest to do the changes in your home directory: `sudo cp /usr/share/applications/midori.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/` and follow @bitseater's instructions in the new file. Your changes will not be overwritten during midori updates.

Comment: I do not think this is what the question asks.it is asking how to get the default icons in the application s

Comment: This is not what I meant. The icons _within_ the applications are changed when changing from default to Numix. Not the icons _of_ the applications.

Comment: sorry, my fault, mistranslation, I will change the answer when I get home

Comment: @Protégé , i have edited the answer. I hope it help you.

Comment: You can also use tweak tool to change the icon theme

Comment: This is an excellent, thorough answer. I'm stunned to see this down voted.